# Index on Lucene not being updated after hibernate "update" operation

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I've got this model for my application where I have an `Element` abstract class and several classes which extends it. This elements have an `ElementType` and could have an `Owner`.
Now I need a REST service that implements a search by text on several fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elements")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@XmlRootElement
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "textanalyzer",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)})
public abstract class Elements implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "elementid")
    private Integer elementId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "code", unique = true)
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "textanalyzer"))
    private String code;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Field(index=Index.YES)
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @JoinColumn(name = "ownerid", referencedColumnName = "ownerid")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Owners owner;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @JoinColumn(name = "elementtypeid", referencedColumnName = "elementtypeid")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ElementTypes elementType; 
    .
    .
    .
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
@XmlRootElement
public class Owners implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ownerid")
    private Integer ownerId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "textanalyzer"))
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    @ContainedIn
    private Collection<Elements> elementsCollection;
    .
    .
    .
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "elementtypes")
@XmlRootElement
public class ElementTypes implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "elementType")
    @ContainedIn
    private Collection<Elements> elementsCollection;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "elementtypeid") 
    private Integer elementTypeId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "code", unique = true)
    @Field(index = Index.YES)
    private String code;
    .
    .
    .
   }
```

An example of class which extends `Element`:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "digitalinputs")
@XmlRootElement
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="elementid")
public class DigitalInputs extends Elements {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "position")
    private int position;


    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private boolean state;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The service code (too long, so here's showed simplified):

```
@Path("/search")
public class SearchController {

    @Context
    ServletContext context;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getElementsSearch(SearchRequestObject sro) {

        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = (FullTextSession)context.getAttribute("fullTextSession"); //indexes are rebuild at the beginning of execution, and the FullTextSession reference is stored in application context     
        try {
            org.apache.lucene.search.Query query;
            QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Elements.class).get();
            if(sro.isDisabled() || sro.isEnabled() || sro.getType() != null) {
                BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new Builder();

                //form the query
                .
                .
                .

            }
            // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
            javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Elements.class); 

            // execute search
            List<Elements> result = jpaQuery.getResultList();

            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(response).build();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e).build();
        }
    }
}
```

This service is working fine, but I have a big problem: When there's an `update`, `merge`, or `saveOrUpdate` execution on hibernate, indexes seems to not update, and the search is returning the old values of the object. That's not happening with `delete` or `save` operations, that are updating the indexes.

I've seen some people having the same issue ([lucene index not getting sync when any update occurs in DB through hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898541/lucene-index-not-getting-sync-when-any-update-occurs-in-db-through-hibernate) , [merge not updating lucene index](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2448182) ), but I didn't get an actual solution. It seems like the `@ContainedIn` tags are ok, and I tried to flush both `Session` and indexes when update operation is called:

```
@Override
public T editEntity(T bean) {
    T t = null;
    try {       
        this.createSession();
        this.createTransaction();

        //this.getSession().merge(bean);
        this.getSession().update(bean);
        this.getSession().flush();
        FullTextSession fts = (FullTextSession)ApplicationUtil.getServletContext().getAttribute("fullTextSession");
        fts.flushToIndexes();
        this.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        this.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }finally {
        this.closeSession();
    }

    return bean;
}
```

But it's still not working. I'd say that I ignored something important, but I can't find helpful info for my case, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem wasn't the index not updating, but the `FullTextSession` referencing an outdated instance of hibernate's `Session`, so basically it was a misunderstanding of the `FullTextSession` and index refreshing.

The solution was updating the `FullTextSession` object with an updated instance of `Session` on each call, instead of storing it in the context:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getElementsSearch(SearchRequestObject sro) {                
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

        .
        .
        .
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e).build();
    }finally {
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the search is returning the old values of the object", do you mean that the getters of entities returned by Hibernate Search return out-of-date data (the values before your update), or do you mean that the returned objects shouldn't have matched your search query anymore, given your updates?
I am going to assume it's the second option.

First you should check that whenever you change the association between an `Elements` and an `Owner`, you update the association on *both* sides; if you just update `Elements.owner` and not `Owner.elementsCollection`, you will experience what you describe.

If you update your associations correctly, then you may have hit a bug such as [HSEARCH-2868](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2868), [HSEARCH-2486](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2486), or even something else. `@ContainedIn` work much better in recent versions, so you should consider upgrading to [Hibernate Search 5.9](http://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.9/) (requires Hibernate ORM 5.2.3+), or at least [Hibernate Search 5.6](http://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.6/) (requires Hibernate ORM 5.0 or 5.1)

If none of this works... please show an example of code where you actually update your entity (i.e. where you call the setters). Your example does not change the entity at all from what I can see, so I suppose you edited out some parts.

Comment: Sorry for not clearing that out in the first place. For example, if I change the `Element` index field `enabled` to `true`, and I search by enabled=true, this element is in the result, but showing the old value (enabled=false). So  my case is the first option you mention.
If I get this same object with REST get call, this object shows the updated value

Comment: Looks like the index is in fact updating, you might have a different problem. You can check the index content using Luke : that should help to understand if you are having a problem with indexing vs querying